# Uniswap V2 why overflow is desired?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, uniswap

I'm analyzing Uniswap V2 core contracts, and have noticed a [comment](https://github.com/Uniswap/v2-core/blob/master/contracts/UniswapV2Pair.sol#L76)

```
// overflow is desired
```

Why overflow is desired?

Because, from my point of view when overflow happens the next line

```
if (timeElapsed > 0 && _reserve0 != 0 && _reserve1 != 0) {
```

never will be true due to wrong `timeElapsed`.

Answer (score 1):

In:

```
uint32 timeElapsed = blockTimestamp - blockTimestampLast; // overflow is desired
```

Since `timeElapsed` is unsigned, if an overflow occurs then its value will necessarily be positive, hence the expression `timeElapsed > 0` will necessarily evaluate to true.

If you're planning to dive into Solidity code, then you probably want to learn the basic concepts of unsigned integers and [Twos Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).

Answer (score 1):

That contract is written in `pragma solidity =0.5.16`. In this version in order to prevent overflow-underflow errors, it has to have SafeMath library checks which is extra operation so it is an extra cost (solidity automatically checks for overflow underflow after v8.0.0)

```
    uint32 timeElapsed = blockTimestamp - blockTimestampLast; // overflow is desired
```

`blockTimestampLast` is when those 2 variables are updated

```
uint public price0CumulativeLast;
uint public price1CumulativeLast;
```

`timeElapsed` type is uint32 which represents unsigned integers with values ranging from 0 to 4,294,967,295. To simplify let's say our range is 0-32 and let's say we have those variables

```
 blockTimestamp=30
 blockTimestampLast=20
```

Therefore `timeElapsed=10`

Assume that 10 seconds passed and we did not update `price0CumulativeLast` and `price1CumulativeLast` so `blockTimestampLast=20`. 10 seconds passed, `blockTimestampLast` did not change we expect that `timeElapsed=20`

After 10 seconds `blockTimestamp` will be 30+10=40. since we assume that our range is 0-32, `blockTimestamp` will be 40-32=8. Now calculate the `timeElapsed`

```
timeElapsed = blockTimestamp - blockTimestampLas
            = 8-20 =-12
```

since we are in 0-32 -12 means 20 seconds. So `timeElapsed=20`. Since the time difference did not change, overflow is desired in this case.

But imagine a case where you are adding total costs and our range is still 0-32. Now when your total cost is 25 and if you add 10 dollars cost, it will be 35 dollars, in our range it is 3 dollars. So this is not desirable.